# Tkinter: What happens when mainloop is called multiple times?

Tags: python, tkinter

I was writing a python program and accidentally called `mainloop` multiple times. I fixed it but I am still wondering what actually happens when you call it multiple times? This is some of my code (you have to press the button around 100 times):

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.resizable(False, False)
button = tk.Button(root, text="Press me multiple times for the crash", command=root.mainloop)
button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

This is the traceback I got:

```py
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1283, in mainloop
    self.tk.mainloop(n)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1709, in __call__
    self.widget._report_exception()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1452, in _report_exception        
    root.report_callback_exception(exc, val, tb)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2093, in report_callback_exception
    import traceback
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\traceback.py", line 5, in <module>
    import linecache
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\linecache.py", line 11, in <module>
    import tokenize
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\tokenize.py", line 94, in <module>
    class TokenInfo(collections.namedtuple('TokenInfo', 'type string start end line')):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\collections\__init__.py", line 397, in namedtuple
    exec(s, namespace)
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded during compilation

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1283, in mainloop
    self.tk.mainloop(n)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1709, in __call__
    self.widget._report_exception()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1452, in _report_exception
    root.report_callback_exception(exc, val, tb)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2093, in report_callback_exception
    import traceback
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\traceback.py", line 5, in <module>
    import linecache
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\linecache.py", line 11, in <module>
    import tokenize
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\tokenize.py", line 94, in <module>
    class TokenInfo(collections.namedtuple('TokenInfo', 'type string start end line')):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\collections\__init__.py", line 397, in namedtuple
    exec(s, namespace)
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded during compilation
Fatal Python error: Cannot recover from stack overflow.

Current thread 0x00000e04 (most recent call first):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705 in __call__
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1283 in mainloop
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705 in __call__
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1283 in mainloop
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705 in __call__
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1283 in mainloop
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705 in __call__
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1283 in mainloop
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705 in __call__
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1283 in mainloop
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2711177) will provide some answers to your question.

Comment: The problem is what happens if you put `mainloop` as a parameter of `tk.Tk().after` not what happens when just simply call `mainloop` multiple times. In the latter, after the window has been closed, `mainloop()` seems to have no effect and does not bring the window up again.

Comment: I made the code simpler and you turns out that you don't even need tkinter's `after`  method. But now you have to press the button around 100 times for the error to occur.

Comment: Recursion is due to calling mainloop() inside mainloop().

Comment: Is there a way to handle that error?

Comment: To fix it, don't call `mainloop()` more than once.  I don't understand why you need to call it multiple times.

Comment: Yes but if I call it multiple times (because of a coding mistake), how can I detect it. Last time it happened it took me 3h to find my mistake.