# Setting stacksize in a python script

Tags: python, stack, csh

I am converting a csh script to a python script. The script calls a memory-intensive executable which requires a very large stack, so the csh script sets the stacksize to unlimited:

```
limit stacksize unlimited
```

When I try to reproduce this script in python, I execute them in a very naive manner, using `os.system`, e.g.:

```
os.system('some_executable')
```

But I do not know how to tell the OS to run these executables with unlimited stacksize. Is there a way to specify stacksize for calls within a python script? Is there some low-level system call that I should be using? And is there a module (similar to shutil) which controls this?

Comment: Attempting to set `rlimit_stack` after [Stack Clash](http://www.openwall.com/lists/oss-security/2017/06/19/1) remediations may result in failure or related problems. Also see Red Hat [Issue 1463241](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1463241)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I have good experience with the following code. It doesn't require any special user permissions:

```
import resource, sys
resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_STACK, (2**29,-1))
sys.setrecursionlimit(10**6)
```

It does however not seem to work with pypy.

If `resource.setrlimit` doesn't work, you can also try using threads:

```
sys.setrecursionlimit(10**6)
import threading
threading.stack_size(2**26)
threading.Thread(target=main).start()
```

Comment: `sys.setrecursionlimit(10**6)` will make the Python interpreter segfault if you overflow the stack.

Comment: Note that, as of this moment, the resource module is not available for Windows OS.

Comment: @ofer.sheffer Still better than the accepted answer which uses `os.system`.

Comment: @ThomasAhle I am `getting the error no module named resource`

Comment: Try installing it. I have resource  module

Comment: @ThomasAhle what is the `-1`? Did you mean `resource.RLIM_INFINITY`?

Answer (score 20):

You can just use the (u)limit command of your shell, if you want:

```
os.system('ulimit -s unlimited; some_executable')
```

Or (probably better) use [resource.setrlimit](http://docs.python.org/library/resource.html):

```
resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_STACK, (resource.RLIM_INFINITY, resource.RLIM_INFINITY))
```

Comment: The first option doesn't work for me; I believe it is because os.system executes commands in the basic shell, sh, rather than bash or tcsh. But your second option is exactly what I needed, thank you. (I can't tell who suggested `setrlimit` first so I am awarding this one, since it includes the explicit code. I am grateful for everyone's answers, though).

Comment: Yeah, I should have mentioned that - some shells use limit, some use ulimit, some allow both; the explicit invocation is a much better idea.

Answer (score 14):

You're looking for the Python [setrlimit](http://docs.python.org/library/resource.html) interface, `resource.RLIMIT_STACK`.

Note that standard users cannot raise their hard limits, only root (well, a process with the `CAP_SYS_RESOURCE` capability (see capabilities(7)) processes can raise their limits; so you may need to use the PAM pam_limits(8) `limits.conf(5)` file to raise the hard limits for the users in question.

Answer (score 4):

You can alter the stack size of the current process via [`threading.stack_size()`](https://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#threading.stack_size), but I don't know if that will be correctly inherited by subprocesses. That interface also requires a specific stack size - "unlimited" isn't an option.