# Py2exe returning RuntimeError:maximum recursion reached

Tags: python, python-2.7, recursion, runtime-error, py2exe

I am attempting to create an exe file on Python 2.7. I downloaded py2exe version 0.6.9 win32. I am getting a `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object.` If I try to run it using Pyinstaller I get the error `TypeError: iteration over non-sequence` which seems like it relates to the same thing that is wrong using py2exe. I'm not sure where it is coming from.

I have gone through the steps: creating a setup.py file:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
setup(console=["MyFileName.py"])
```

Then running `python setup.py py2exe --help` from the command window, then `python setup.py py2exe`

I understand that the RunTimeError happens when the code encounters infinite recursions, but my .py file does not have this error. I tried:

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(5000)
```

based on another StackOverflow answer but am still getting the same error. 
I have included a Traceback (as much as my cmd window will show)

```
    self.scan_code(co, m)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 423, in scan_code
    self._safe_import_hook(name, m, fromlist, level=level)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 332, in _safe_import_h
ook
    self.import_hook(name, caller, level=level)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 719, in import_hook
    return Base.import_hook(self,name,caller,fromlist,level)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 137, in import_hook
    m = self.load_tail(q, tail)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 214, in load_tail
    m = self.import_module(head, mname, m)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 724, in import_module
    r = Base.import_module(self,partnam,fqname,parent)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 284, in import_module
    m = self.load_module(fqname, fp, pathname, stuff)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 730, in load_module
    r = Base.load_module(self, fqname, fp, pathname, (suffix, mode, typ))
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 314, in load_module
    self.scan_code(co, m)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 423, in scan_code
    self._safe_import_hook(name, m, fromlist, level=level)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 332, in _safe_import_h
ook
    self.import_hook(name, caller, level=level)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 719, in import_hook
    return Base.import_hook(self,name,caller,fromlist,level)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 137, in import_hook
    m = self.load_tail(q, tail)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 214, in load_tail
    m = self.import_module(head, mname, m)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 724, in import_module
    r = Base.import_module(self,partnam,fqname,parent)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 284, in import_module
    m = self.load_module(fqname, fp, pathname, stuff)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 730, in load_module
    r = Base.load_module(self, fqname, fp, pathname, (suffix, mode, typ))
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 314, in load_module
    self.scan_code(co, m)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 423, in scan_code
    self._safe_import_hook(name, m, fromlist, level=level)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 332, in _safe_import_h
ook
    self.import_hook(name, caller, level=level)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 719, in import_hook
    return Base.import_hook(self,name,caller,fromlist,level)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 137, in import_hook
    m = self.load_tail(q, tail)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 214, in load_tail
    m = self.import_module(head, mname, m)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 724, in import_module
    r = Base.import_module(self,partnam,fqname,parent)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 284, in import_module
    m = self.load_module(fqname, fp, pathname, stuff)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 730, in load_module
    r = Base.load_module(self, fqname, fp, pathname, (suffix, mode, typ))
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 314, in load_module
    self.scan_code(co, m)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 456, in scan_code
    self.scan_code(c, m)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 423, in scan_code
    self._safe_import_hook(name, m, fromlist, level=level)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 332, in _safe_import_h
ook
    self.import_hook(name, caller, level=level)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 719, in import_hook
    return Base.import_hook(self,name,caller,fromlist,level)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 137, in import_hook
    m = self.load_tail(q, tail)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 214, in load_tail
    m = self.import_module(head, mname, m)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 724, in import_module
    r = Base.import_module(self,partnam,fqname,parent)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 284, in import_module
    m = self.load_module(fqname, fp, pathname, stuff)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 730, in load_module
    r = Base.load_module(self, fqname, fp, pathname, (suffix, mode, typ))
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 314, in load_module
    self.scan_code(co, m)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 456, in scan_code
    self.scan_code(c, m)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 456, in scan_code
    self.scan_code(c, m)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 423, in scan_code
    self._safe_import_hook(name, m, fromlist, level=level)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 343, in _safe_import_h
ook
    self.import_hook(name, caller, [sub], level=level)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 719, in import_hook
    return Base.import_hook(self,name,caller,fromlist,level)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 141, in import_hook
    self.ensure_fromlist(m, fromlist)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 231, in ensure_fromlis
t
    submod = self.import_module(sub, subname, m)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 724, in import_module
    r = Base.import_module(self,partnam,fqname,parent)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 284, in import_module
    m = self.load_module(fqname, fp, pathname, stuff)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 730, in load_module
    r = Base.load_module(self, fqname, fp, pathname, (suffix, mode, typ))
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 295, in load_module
    m = self.load_package(fqname, pathname)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 471, in load_package
    self.load_module(fqname, fp, buf, stuff)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 730, in load_module
    r = Base.load_module(self, fqname, fp, pathname, (suffix, mode, typ))
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 314, in load_module
    self.scan_code(co, m)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 446, in scan_code
    self._safe_import_hook(name, m, fromlist, level=level)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 332, in _safe_import_h
ook
    self.import_hook(name, caller, level=level)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 719, in import_hook
    return Base.import_hook(self,name,caller,fromlist,level)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 136, in import_hook
    q, tail = self.find_head_package(parent, name)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 192, in find_head_pack
age
    q = self.import_module(head, qname, parent)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 724, in import_module
    r = Base.import_module(self,partnam,fqname,parent)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 284, in import_module
    m = self.load_module(fqname, fp, pathname, stuff)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 730, in load_module
    r = Base.load_module(self, fqname, fp, pathname, (suffix, mode, typ))
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 314, in load_module
    self.scan_code(co, m)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 423, in scan_code
    self._safe_import_hook(name, m, fromlist, level=level)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 332, in _safe_import_h
ook
    self.import_hook(name, caller, level=level)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 719, in import_hook
    return Base.import_hook(self,name,caller,fromlist,level)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 137, in import_hook
    m = self.load_tail(q, tail)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 214, in load_tail
    m = self.import_module(head, mname, m)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 724, in import_module
    r = Base.import_module(self,partnam,fqname,parent)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 284, in import_module
    m = self.load_module(fqname, fp, pathname, stuff)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 730, in load_module
    r = Base.load_module(self, fqname, fp, pathname, (suffix, mode, typ))
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 314, in load_module
    self.scan_code(co, m)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 456, in scan_code
    self.scan_code(c, m)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 423, in scan_code
    self._safe_import_hook(name, m, fromlist, level=level)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 332, in _safe_import_h
ook
    self.import_hook(name, caller, level=level)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 719, in import_hook
    return Base.import_hook(self,name,caller,fromlist,level)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 137, in import_hook
    m = self.load_tail(q, tail)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 214, in load_tail
    m = self.import_module(head, mname, m)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 724, in import_module
    r = Base.import_module(self,partnam,fqname,parent)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 284, in import_module
    m = self.load_module(fqname, fp, pathname, stuff)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 730, in load_module
    r = Base.load_module(self, fqname, fp, pathname, (suffix, mode, typ))
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 295, in load_module
    m = self.load_package(fqname, pathname)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 471, in load_package
    self.load_module(fqname, fp, buf, stuff)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 730, in load_module
    r = Base.load_module(self, fqname, fp, pathname, (suffix, mode, typ))
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 314, in load_module
    self.scan_code(co, m)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 449, in scan_code
    self._safe_import_hook(parent.__name__, None, fromlist, level=0)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 343, in _safe_import_h
ook
    self.import_hook(name, caller, [sub], level=level)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 719, in import_hook
    return Base.import_hook(self,name,caller,fromlist,level)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 141, in import_hook
    self.ensure_fromlist(m, fromlist)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 231, in ensure_fromlis
t
    submod = self.import_module(sub, subname, m)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 724, in import_module
    r = Base.import_module(self,partnam,fqname,parent)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 284, in import_module
    m = self.load_module(fqname, fp, pathname, stuff)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 730, in load_module
    r = Base.load_module(self, fqname, fp, pathname, (suffix, mode, typ))
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 295, in load_module
    m = self.load_package(fqname, pathname)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 471, in load_package
    self.load_module(fqname, fp, buf, stuff)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 730, in load_module
    r = Base.load_module(self, fqname, fp, pathname, (suffix, mode, typ))
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 314, in load_module
    self.scan_code(co, m)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 423, in scan_code
    self._safe_import_hook(name, m, fromlist, level=level)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 332, in _safe_import_h
ook
    self.import_hook(name, caller, level=level)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 719, in import_hook
    return Base.import_hook(self,name,caller,fromlist,level)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 137, in import_hook
    m = self.load_tail(q, tail)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 214, in load_tail
    m = self.import_module(head, mname, m)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 724, in import_module
    r = Base.import_module(self,partnam,fqname,parent)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 284, in import_module
    m = self.load_module(fqname, fp, pathname, stuff)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 730, in load_module
    r = Base.load_module(self, fqname, fp, pathname, (suffix, mode, typ))
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 314, in load_module
    self.scan_code(co, m)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 456, in scan_code
    self.scan_code(c, m)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 423, in scan_code
    self._safe_import_hook(name, m, fromlist, level=level)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 332, in _safe_import_h
ook
    self.import_hook(name, caller, level=level)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 719, in import_hook
    return Base.import_hook(self,name,caller,fromlist,level)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 136, in import_hook
    q, tail = self.find_head_package(parent, name)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 199, in find_head_pack
age
    q = self.import_module(head, qname, parent)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 724, in import_module
    r = Base.import_module(self,partnam,fqname,parent)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 284, in import_module
    m = self.load_module(fqname, fp, pathname, stuff)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 730, in load_module
    r = Base.load_module(self, fqname, fp, pathname, (suffix, mode, typ))
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 295, in load_module
    m = self.load_package(fqname, pathname)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 471, in load_package
    self.load_module(fqname, fp, buf, stuff)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 730, in load_module
    r = Base.load_module(self, fqname, fp, pathname, (suffix, mode, typ))
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 314, in load_module
    self.scan_code(co, m)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 423, in scan_code
    self._safe_import_hook(name, m, fromlist, level=level)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 343, in _safe_import_h
ook
    self.import_hook(name, caller, [sub], level=level)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 719, in import_hook
    return Base.import_hook(self,name,caller,fromlist,level)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 141, in import_hook
    self.ensure_fromlist(m, fromlist)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 231, in ensure_fromlis
t
    submod = self.import_module(sub, subname, m)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 724, in import_module
    r = Base.import_module(self,partnam,fqname,parent)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 284, in import_module
    m = self.load_module(fqname, fp, pathname, stuff)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 730, in load_module
    r = Base.load_module(self, fqname, fp, pathname, (suffix, mode, typ))
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 295, in load_module
    m = self.load_package(fqname, pathname)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 471, in load_package
    self.load_module(fqname, fp, buf, stuff)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 730, in load_module
    r = Base.load_module(self, fqname, fp, pathname, (suffix, mode, typ))
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 314, in load_module
    self.scan_code(co, m)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 423, in scan_code
    self._safe_import_hook(name, m, fromlist, level=level)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 332, in _safe_import_h
ook
    self.import_hook(name, caller, level=level)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 719, in import_hook
    return Base.import_hook(self,name,caller,fromlist,level)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 137, in import_hook
    m = self.load_tail(q, tail)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 214, in load_tail
    m = self.import_module(head, mname, m)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 724, in import_module
    r = Base.import_module(self,partnam,fqname,parent)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 284, in import_module
    m = self.load_module(fqname, fp, pathname, stuff)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 730, in load_module
    r = Base.load_module(self, fqname, fp, pathname, (suffix, mode, typ))
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 295, in load_module
    m = self.load_package(fqname, pathname)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 463, in load_package
    m = self.add_module(fqname)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 478, in add_module
    self.modules[fqname] = m = Module(fqname)
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

in MyFileName.py I import the following modules:

```
import __future__    
#from __future__ import division
import itertools
from Tkinter import *
import numpy as np
from collections import OrderedDict
from bokeh.plotting import ColumnDataSource, figure, show, output_file
from bokeh.models import HoverTool
import pandas as pd
import datetime as datetime
import pandas.util.testing as tm; tm.N = 3
import pyodbc
import csv
from bokeh.charts import Bar
from bokeh.palettes import RdYlGn11
import calendar
import dateutil
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5061582/setting-stacksize-in-a-python-script/16248113#16248113

Comment: @J.daSilva I followed your commend and tried adding the import resource,sys and other lines to my .py file I am converting. I get an ImportError of No module named resource if I try to run it. I still got the same error. Do I need to put that code somewhere else?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/resource.html#module-resource

Comment: @J.daSilva still not working :/