# Recursive function in python for Fibonacci sequence

Tags: python, recursion, intellij-idea

I am trying to use a recursive function to calculate the fibonacci sequence. This is what I have come up with:

```
import sys
new_recursion_limit=3000
sys.setrecursionlimit(new_recursion_limit)
fibonacci_cache = {}


def fibonacci(n):
    if n in fibonacci_cache:
        return fibonacci_cache[n]
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        result = fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2)
        fibonacci_cache[n] = result
        return result



number = int(input("Enter the number for fiboonacci value: "))
result = fibonacci(number)
print(f"The value of fibbonaci {number} is {result}")
```

I used chatGPT so that I can have a basic idea to implement the method. The error I receive is a RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded. even for the int 5 I am receiving this error. I am a beginner in programming and I am trying to implement the recursive function so that I have a proper idea about the functioning. Can anyone please help me with this error?

When I received the error I tried to use sys function to se a recursive limit. Th repetation is 1000+ in this case. I was expecting the recursive function to work normally. but I still receive the error.

Comment: if `n` is `2` what is `fibonacci(n - 2)` since you only treat n of 1 as a special case....

Comment: Note: [The recursion limit is not the limit on recursion but the maximum depth of the python interpreter stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38265839/max-recursion-is-not-exactly-what-sys-getrecursionlimit-claims-how-come/38265931#38265931)

Comment: Add a `print(n)` at the top of your fibonacci function. See what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes when your code gets to the recursive call of `fibonacci(2)`.

Inside this call, it will then call `fibonacci(1)` and `fibonacci(0)`.

In the `fibonacci(1)` call, it will hit the `if n == 1` condition, and properly terminate with a return value of 1.

But the `fibonacci(0)` call does not stop; it calls `fibonacci(-1)` and `fibonacci(-2)`.  And the negative numbers just keep growing from there.

You need to account for the case where `n` is zero.

Answer (score 2):

As has been pointed out, the core issue here is that you need to account for two special cases, `n == 1` and `n == 0`. You can do that in your code, but since you are manually initializing a cache you can also just do it there.

```py
## ----------------
## initialize our cache in a way that will
## handle our special cases. Note that this
## also simplifies our method.
## ----------------
fibonacci_cache = {0: 0, 1: 1}
## ----------------

def fibonacci(n):
    if n not in fibonacci_cache:
        fibonacci_cache[n] = fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)
    return fibonacci_cache[n]

number = int(input("Enter the number for fiboonacci value: "))
result = fibonacci(number)
print(f"The value of fibbonaci {number} is {result}")
```

At this point, you might add in a test to ensure that `n >= 0` and throw a `ValueError` if not, but I'll leave that to you to consider.

Answer (score 0):

Assume `n=2`, your `else` in your function would be met, then it faces `fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2)`, which is `fibonacci(1) + fibonacci(0)`.

`fibonacci(1)` is 1, but you didn't provide anything for `fibonacci(0)`, so again your else would be met and you will have `fibonacci(-1) + fibonacci(-2)` and this will happen infinitely.

So simply just provide a return value for case of `n=0`:

```py
def fibonacci(n):
    if n in fibonacci_cache:
        return fibonacci_cache[n]
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    ...
```

Answer (score -1):

Look at what your function does when it receives n=2

Comment: Seems to be a comment, not an answer.