# Difference between my code and the one explicitly using Memoization

Tags: python, python-3.x, memoization

Recognizing the inefficiency of a simple recursive method for generating Fibonacci numbers because of repetitive calculations, I looked into memoization to hasten the runtime. I wrote a piece of code and then contrasted it to Python's built-in implementation that I discovered online.

I'm curious to understand why the online implementation excels, despite both utilizing a dictionary to cache values and prevent redundancy. Although I recognize that minor variations in execution time are common, the significant contrast between my code and the alternative becomes apparent for larger values of N.

- My Code

```py
import timeit

my_dict = {}

def fibonacci(n):
    """ To print the fibonacci series efficiently """
    if n == 1:
        x = 0
        my_dict[n] = x
        return x

    elif n == 2:
        fibonacci(1)
        x = 1
        my_dict[n] = x
        return x

    elif n == 3:
        fibonacci(2)
        x = 1
        my_dict[n] = x
        return x

    elif n > 3:
        fibonacci(n-1)
        x = my_dict[n-2] + my_dict[n-1]
        my_dict[n] = x
        return x

number = int(input("Enter N: "))

t = timeit.timeit(lambda: fibonacci(number), number=10)

fib = fibonacci(number)

print(f"Number: {fib}\n Time: {t:.32f}")
```

- Output

```
$ python 06_fibo_dict.py
Enter N: 100
Number: 218922995834555169026
Time: 0.00059320009313523769378662109375


$ python 06_fibo_dict.py
Enter N: 200
Number: 173402521172797813159685037284371942044301
Time: 0.00105599989183247089385986328125
```

- Code I found online

```
import timeit

def fibonacci(n, cache={}):
    if n in cache:
        return cache[n]

    if n == 1:
        result = 0

    elif n == 2:
        result = 1

    else:
        result = fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)

    cache[n] = result
    return result

number = int(input("Enter N: "))

t = timeit.timeit(lambda: fibonacci(number), number=10)

fib = fibonacci(number)

print(f"Number: {fib}\n Time: {t:.32f}")
```

- Output

```
$ python 07_fibo_memo.py
Enter N: 100
Number: 218922995834555169026
Time: 0.00000469991937279701232910156250


$ python 07_fibo_memo.py
Enter N: 200
Number: 173402521172797813159685037284371942044301
Time: 0.00000709993764758110046386718750
```

Comment: If you are going to create your own dictionary to cache results, initialize it properly so you don't have to handle the special cases in code:  See : https://stackoverflow.com/a/76836917/218663

Comment: I don't think `time.time` is recommended for timing code, use `timeit`.

Comment: Since you fixed the bug pointed out by @KellyBundy the timings seem a lot closer, probably within the error margin of your timing method.  Is this question even still relevant?

Answer (score 1):

Because your code is recursing all the way down to 0, without a shortcut when it already has the lesser values in the map, it's doing unnecessary work.  The version you found elsewhere will only need to do the work from 700 down to 500 on your second call.

Comment: I like how this just became much more relevant now that they did switch to timeit :-)