# Python3 – RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded during compilation

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, command-line-arguments, recursionerror

I am running a scraper that parses data from specified websites and populates the HTML of a webpage to be later updated. The amount of data that is being scraped and parse is rather large, and the String containing the HTML of the webpage is a couple of hundred lines long.

I am using lists of dictionaries to insert the correct values into the HTML String through concatenation. After adding a certain amount of concatenations, I tried running my script to confirm that it was working properly, and I encountered this error:

`RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded during compilation`

When I delete the added lines which add to the String containing the HTML of the page, the script runs fine.

I tried using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16248113/13971586), but nothing changed.

I also tried to separate the String concatenation into a separate `.py` file and then importing that file and calling the function, but it continues to throw the `RecursionError`.

On a third shot, I attempted to use `subprocess.run()`, but I received `ValueErrors` because dictionaries cannot be passed as command line arguments.

I am running MacOS 11.4. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Python itself puts a limit on the number of recursions allowed no matter how much memory each recursion takes.

Comment: P.S. a couple of hundred lines of HTML isn't very big.